# Why is macOS forcibly renaming my USB drive?

Tags: finder, hard-drive, usb, filesystem, hfs+

I have a USB Drive named "Cuthbert", and various apps use paths starting with `/Volumes/Cuthbert` when it is plugged in.  However, my laptop is putting it at `/Volumes/Cuthbert 1`, and won't let me rename it, even though there `/Volumes/Cuthbert` leads to nothing.  (It shows up when I `ls`, but does not show up in the Finder, and there is nothing there.)

What is going on?  How can I fix and *prevent* this ***frustrating*** situation?

Comment: Eject the drive then manually go and remove `/Volumes/Cuthbert`  then re-insert the drive.  Is the problem fixed?

Comment: Yes, that fixed the presenting problem—thank you!  How do I fix the _underlying_ problem so I can prevent this from ever happening again?

Comment: It's not really a problem per se.  It's when the first mount doesn't get properly unmounted, the directory stays.  Then when you plug in the drive it "thinks" it's already mounted and appends the `-1`.  You don't want to change this behavior because it's your safety net if you plug in two drives with the exact same name.

Comment: I guess if we're narrowly referring to the _renaming_ behavior then you're right: it's necessary.  But if we're talking about the whole set of behaviors here, then I absolutely want the behavior to change. First, I want it to properly unmount. Secondly, I need to know when it maps to a different name, because apps that are depending on it being where it's supposed to be are immediately broken, and I get no notification of this.  My "automatic" backups of my iPhone with iMazing don't happen, and I'm not alerted to that.

Comment: There are any number of reasons why something doesn't (un)mount properly - this is the reason for this functionality.  As to your second point, your apps, scripts or whatever should be checking that the mount actually exists and generate and error if they don't, not just fail silently.

Comment: @iconoclast I'd guess that one of the apps that use the path /Volumes/Cuthbert is *creating* that folder when it doesn't exist (i.e. when the drive isn't mounted / has just vanished), thus creating the problem. Try running `sudo fs_usage | grep "mkdir .*/Volumes/Cuthbert"` in a spare Terminal window, and leave it running until the problem reappears. Then check its output to get some idea what the culprit is.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you properly unmount the USB drive when you remove it. If a volume name already exists in a system and you try to add a volume with the same name it will append -*n* to the volume name.